# How to supply power to a DC motor which will be used for an electric skateboard?

Tags: power, batteries, dc-motor

I bought a 775 DC motor 15000RPM 12-36V. I'm planing to build an electric skateboard with it. But I don't know how to supply enough power to this motor in order for it to carry me with a decent speed. I actually don't even know if I bought the right motor for it.

I tried something for testing purposes:

Firstly, connected the motor to a 12V 800mA power supply, didn't do much.

Secondly, I combined 12 piece of 1.5V alkaline batteries to get 18V, then connected the motor directly in parallel. The motor got 13.7V and was drawing about 0.7A.

Thirdly, I used a boost converter circuit. When takes in 18V batteries, also draws a current about 1.5A and gives out 32V. When I connected the motor to the output terminal of boost converter, the motor was drawing 0.65A current and got about 13-15V.

In conclusion, I don't know what kind of battery to buy. High power, lipo batteries are pretty expensive and i don't want to leave it to chance.

Does my 775 DC motor qualify for electric skateboard task?
If so or not, how can I decide for the decent battery and motor for it?

Comment: What are the specs for this motor? Try connecting to a car battery…

Comment: Measure motor DCR resistance. That determines your start current not rated at 12V which affects heat rise.   Your coasting no load current will be only 1% or so of this which is what you measured.  You bought a cheap 4W motor that may draw 40W on startup. Good luck but not enough power.  Compute Wh for battery requirements and expect you need 100W motor min.  350W typ.

Comment: https://www.amazon.ca/s?k=e+skateboard+motor&gclid=Cj0KCQjwpv2TBhDoARIsALBnVnmal-J_B-lCswrz7XK9jpnO28FepG5WNhmbt8QBYziMsj2Lns6CezIaApObEALw_wcB&hvadid=512576204118&hvdev=c&hvlocphy=9000793&hvnetw=g&hvqmt=e&hvrand=3888203663571954203&hvtargid=kwd-324925410202&hydadcr=4634_10582737&tag=googcana-20&ref=pd_sl_14kswx5px0_e

Comment: How many wires do you have coming out of the motor? I have an electric unicycle and it uses a Brushless DC electric motor (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brushless_DC_electric_motor)

Comment: just two wires coming out, and the dealer says it's a brushless dc motor. I don't know the power rating. How can we know which motor to buy if they don't write power rating of the motor ?

Comment: please add a link to the motor, or add a picture of the motor

Comment: Usually good sellers give a datasheet with the products, like motors, that one buys. Cheap stuff tends to have important things like that missing…

Comment: forget 1.5 V alkaline batteries. You need a few hundred watts to run a suitable motor. That's 10 A at 20 V as a minimum.

Comment: A ‘775’ motor looks like something you’d find in a battery drill. If that is the case, then you’ll need something like a lead acid, Li Ion or Li Po battery to deliver enough current as well as gearing to suit. I’d suggest you get hold of a cheapy scooter and work from that. In my area there’s plenty of them thrown out when the batteries die.

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/15000RPM-Shredders-Sprayers-Cleaners-Electrical/dp/B07GLFMJYD/ref=sr_1_6?crid=2SY9UEUFINBHL&keywords=775+motor+15000&qid=1652554875&sprefix=775+motor+1500%2Caps%2C181&sr=8-6

Comment: this is the motor

Comment: definitely not a brushless motor

Comment: That's a toy or vacuum motor

Comment: Can you suggest a model ?